# LESS compiled Bootstrap causes carousel trip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, animation, less, carousel

I've got a css file compiled from the Bootstrap LESS files. When I run the carousel plugin it kind of "trips" when switching to a next slide causing image partially disappear in the left part when sliding right and its right part disappear when sliding to the left. Same for the accordion - it doesn't move smoothly but goes kind of abruptly. However if I include the original bootstrap.css file after the compiled css everything works ok. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer myself. Seems like I've created yet another .transition() variable in my styles.less file which interfered with the original one. Changing it's name resolved the issue.